# Magento Full Page Cache & Load Testing

Tags: mysql, cache, magento, jmeter

```
Magento Enterprise 9
Full Page Caching is on
Cache depth: 1 (ex. catalog.html?p=1)
```

Current results from JMeter after about 1,000 samples:

```
Throughput:
Homepage: 8.5/sec - ~40kb
Catalog: 6.1/sec - ~65kb
```

Error rate is very low, 0% for homepage, and 1.1% for catalog.

There's no reverse proxy server or a load-balancer in front of the server yet.

When the test is running, I can see a spike in requests being sent to the MySQL server.
 Does Magento full page caching not fully cache the pages, or is there something wrong with the state of cache?

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you post jMeter profile - depending on your cookie configuration, you will find differing results from EE's FPC
2. Also, how have you configured your cache backend, to use File/Backend/DB/Memcache/Redis? http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/what-is-memcache-actually-caching-in-magento/)

Both of the above points will effect the frequency and type of SQL queries being executed. But I wouldn't rely solely on FPC - especially when benchmarking. It makes a lot more sense to disable FPC but leave the remaining caches enabled, so as not to skew your benchmarking.